# GWT equivalent for .NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, gwt

I enjoy GWT because I can have compile-time type safe code that runs in the browser. However, I like C# a lot better than Java. Is there some good way to have C# compile to Javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not exactly, but ScriptSharp is very close:

http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp)?

Answer (score 2):

SharpKit is what you want.  It actually does much more than GWT is capable.

http://sharpkit.net

Answer (score 0):

C# to JavaScript compiler: [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp)

This page might be useful too: [altjs.org](http://altjs.org)

Answer (score 0):

As GWT compiler converting the java libraries into respective javascript,there is no exact 
option is provided for C#,but ScriptSharp behavior is much similar to GWT.